# Initialising a struct variable to Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Is there a way to declare a variable as Nullable in c#?

```
struct MyStruct {        
    int _yer, _ner;

    public MyStruct() {

        _yer = Nullable<int>; //This does not work.
        _ner = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sir psycho: remember you can't declare explicit parameterless constructors in structs in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_yer must be declare as int? or Nullable<int>.

```
    int? _yer;
    int _ner;

    public MyStruct(int? ver, int ner) {

        _yer = ver;
        _ner = ner;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
    Nullable<int> _yer;
    int _ner;

    public MyStruct(Nullable<int> ver, int ner) {

        _yer = ver;
        _ner = ner;
    }
}
```

**Remember that structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors.**

```
error CS0568: Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors
```

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your variable like this:

```
int? yer;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(VS.80).aspx):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    private int? _yer, _ner;
    public MyStruct(int? yer, int? ner)
    {
        _yer = yer;
        _ner = ner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring _yer as type Nullable initially, rather than as a standard int.